# How to call a keyboard key with javascript or a C language

Tags: javascript, c++, keyboard

I am trying to figure out a way to programmatically press a key that the operating system (Windows) can read, rather then just printing the characters as a string.

Goal: To make a small standalone helper application to automatically press hotkeys at specific times in order to change the lighting inside of a building that is controlled by one Windows PC. I would like to code the application if javascript if capable, or a C language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, an application can generate keyboard events using [SendKeys.Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) and related variants. See [Simulating Mouse and Keyboard Events in Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms171548(v=VS.110).aspx). However, this is really not  a good or stable way to communicate from one application to another...

Communication between apps via the UI is fragile, because applications may change their UI at any time (and may not be aware that others are relying on it in a programmatic way like this). Instead, proper communication between apps is done through an Application Programmer Interface (API). Since this is a home automation sort of system, you may wish to consider adopting / using devices that adopt one of many standards in development around how to communicate between devices and the kind of messages that are to be understood by devices. For example, Google's project Weave and Apple's HomeKit both have standard ways to tell a light to turn on or off.

Comment: Hi thanks. I am aware of the conners you stated, but for this application the UI does not change, and i am monitoring the applications 24/7 while it is running so your solution is exactly what i need. For future automation, i plan to use technologies that has an API, or program an Ardrino to job specs. Over source code should be less then 50 to 100 lines. Just somethings simple as a helper app. Thanks!